# SQL Question - how do I select all emails that belong to a list of domains from two tables?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have two tables here: One holds a list of subscriber emails:

```
(ID, email)
```

and the other holds a list of domains:

```
(ID, domain)
```

I want to figure out a sql statement that allows me to `select *` the email addresses which belong to the domains listed in the domain table assuming that all emails are of the form:

```
name@domain
```

Can this be done in sql or do I need to write a script for this?

Comment: Is your schema really 

ID,email

and

ID, DOMAIN

? if so, then your schema is pretty light for having separate tables.

Comment: @Jeremy: Yeah, but talk about normalized... ;-)

Comment: Not really I'm just over simplifying this here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
SELECT 
    sub_emails.email
FROM 
    sub_emails
INNER JOIN
    list_domains ON 
        (sub_emails.email LIKE concat('%@', list_domains.domain_name));
```

Be aware that this will require a full table scan of `sub_emails`, since MySQL does not support function based indexes yet. Therefore this would become very slow if `sub_emails` contains many records.

Comment: i'd probably do '%@' or else someone may use a domain name as username. =D

Answer (score 2):

Start here:

```
select email from EmailTable 
where substring(email, charindex('@', email) + 1, LEN(@test))
in (select domain from DomainTable)
```

This will fail if any of your emails are missing the @, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT email FROM emailTable WHERE 
    SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@',email)) IN (SELECT domain FROM domainTable)
```

Comment: LOCATE() is good, but it should be (SELECT domain FROM domainTable)

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @myregexp := CONCAT( 
 '@(',
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( REPLACE(domain,'.','\.') SEPARATOR '|' ) FROM `domains` ) , 
 ')$'
);

SELECT * 
FROM `emails` 
WHERE email
REGEXP @myregexp
```

Comment: Not so ideal because a) regex is really slow and b) it would recognize "blahdomain.com" when actually "bla.domain.com" is in the list.

Comment: Ad a - any join in this case would be slow, until adding extra indexed column domain_id in emails table
ad b - thanks, I forgot subdomains